# HTML: local web css refer to internet link?

Tags: html, css

I'm reading sourcecode of html files that has something like:

```
link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="https://<internet-link.../abc.css" />
```

This website is completely local - run without internet, does this mean some part of this file would not run as expected because its style need to fetch from internet?

Comment: What is the question? If it's just a YES/NO question. You can disable internet, clear browser cache and test it.

Comment: yup its clear that `css` loading from internet.

Comment: Convert it to local file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, without internet no style will be applied. To fix this, you can initially include your online CSS file link and also use a local fallback. If the online file is not found or there is no internet connection, it will include the local one. For example:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        if ($('body').css('color') !== '#000') {
            $('head').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/abc.css">');
        }
    });
})(window.jQuery);</script>
```

This checks if CSS from your online file was applied to your page and if not, it loads the local CSS file.